# How much country-side can I see by train [Prague-Kutna Hora]?

Tags: trains, czech-republic, prague, rural

I am visiting Prague in the near future.

I really want to travel somewhere outside of Prague that doesn't have too many tourists. I really want to experience more than just the tourist traps and constant floods of people pushing you.

I have read a review that Kutna Hora is good for this and you can get to it by train, which does not cost a lot of money.

My question is, during the journey (by train) how much country can you see of Czech republic? I am really interested in seeing some of the more rural parts.

Comment: @JonathanReez Many train journeys are much more scenic than "some fields and towns". Isn't it reasonable to ask if this is one of them. Do you know that all you'll see is fields and towns or is that just a guess?

Comment: @DavidRicherby I agree with this. When I travel somewhere within the UK there are more scenic routes than others. Some are just grim, whereas others you can actually get a feel for how things are etc.. Make sense?

Comment: I would recommend you to visit beautiful Český ráj (Czech Eden) at Jičín

Comment: @JonathanReez OK. Then that sounds like an answer, rather than a comment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've taken many-many train rides in **Stredocesky Kraj** (the district surrounding Prague). The only things you can see are train stations, industrial zones, small forests, and agricultural fields. Whether or not you consider this exciting depends on what you like to see during your travels.

You can see what a typical train ride in Czech Republic looks like in this 2.5 hour video of a trip between **Prague** and **Ostrava**:

[image]

Comment: I just rode in a car along a similar route across the Czech republic, and I can add that it's about like this by road as well. I think it *is* beautiful country, in a quiet agricultural way — but it's not dramatic like going through the Alps or anything.

Comment: @mattdm I don't like the term "beautiful country" because it begs the question of where all the ugly ones are :) But it does have a sort of a pastoral beauty.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is for all others who are considering the same trip:

Kutna Hora is one of the several tours ran by Prague Tourist Agencies, so not exactly without tourists. Many busloads are coming to Ossuary, St.Barbora Catedral and having lunch there before returning back to Prague. Taking a bus from Prague and walking around on your own will be much more enjoyable and just a small fraction of what the travel agencies charge.

If you really want to go, take a bus which is leaving from Cerny Most terminal to Kutna Hora. We enjoyed the bus trip very much as it goes through small towns and villages, stopping in each of them. You can really see how ordinary Czechs live. The bus trip is also cheaper than the train.  To get to Ossuary, you take a very short ride on Kutna Hora local bus to Sedlec. Bus stops close to a small chapel (you will see parked busses), Ossuary is very small and often packed with tourist groups.  However, the city of Kutna Hora is nice and worth your time.  Avoid restaurant U Sv. Barbory where I had a worse lunch in my life.